# Show that if $f$ is a proper surjective map which is locally injective then $f$ must be a covering map

Tags: general-topology, functions, covering-spaces

> Suppose $f :X \to Y$ is a continuous proper map between locally compact Hausdorff spaces. Show that if $f$ is a surjective map which is locally injective then $f$ must be a covering map.

It is well known that $f$ is a closed map. Suppose $y \in Y$ be any element then by properness $f^{-1}(y)$ must be a finite set. Suppose $f^{-1}(y)$ ={$x_1,x_2,...,x_n$} then as $X$ is Hausdorff we get open nbhds $U_i$'s separating $x_i$'s. But I am unable to see how to proceed now. Thank you for your help.

Comment: If you knew that $f(U_i)$ is a neighbourhood of $y$ for each $i$, could you then continue?

Comment: @DanielFischer that i ofcourse know.Regards,

Comment: Apparently this is not true. Let $Y$ be a closed line segment and $X$ the union of $Y$ with an isolated point. Let $f:X\to Y$ fixing $Y$ (and mapping the isolated point of $X$ anywhere). Then $f$ satisfies all those properties but is not a local homeomorphism, thus not a covering map.

Comment: Luiz gave a counterexample, which made me discover a flaw in my answer below, so I deleted it.

Comment: Dear @StefanHamcke I'm curious to know the flaw of your proof.I'm unable to find that,please tell me.Regards,

Comment: The flaw is in the first paragraph. Each point $x$ has a neighborhood $U$ such that $f$ is injective on $U$. By local compactness, we find a compact neighborhood $V\subseteq U$, and $f|_V:V\to f(V)$ is a homeomorphism since it is a map from a compact to a Hausdorff space. However, $f(V)$ need not be a neighborhood of $f(x)$. The counterexample by Luiz illustrates this. Just look at the neighborhood $\{p\}$ at the isolated point $p$ of $X$.

Comment: @StefanHamcke I see, Thanks a lot!